# [[nodiscard]] in std::function return type definition?

Tags: c++, c++17, std, nodiscard

I'm wondering if is there a way to have something like this:

```cpp
using CallbackType = std::function<[[nodiscard]]bool(void)>;
```

(I know above code won't be compiled and complains that `nodiscard` can't be applied to types!)

My goal is to enforce the caller of the callback to check the return value of it!

Comment: Derive from std::function and add [[nodiscard]] to operator() ?

Comment: I thought about that, but deriving from std::function is discouraged by the community due to its potential issues.

Comment: @AlirezaHosseini Note that while public inheritance from standard library types is discouraged for very good reasons, private inheritance is absolutely fine. This here screams for that.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct Function {
  using Fn = R (*)(Args...);

  Fn fn;

  explicit Function(Fn fn) : fn{fn} {}

  [[nodiscard]] R operator()(Args... args) {
    return (*fn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};

template <typename R, typename... Args>
Function(R (*)(Args...)) -> Function<R, Args...>;


bool bar(const int& x) { return x % 2 == 0; }

int main() {
  Function{&bar}(10);
}
```

Warning:

```
Compiler stderr

<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:24:17: warning: ignoring return value of 'R Function<R, Args>::operator()(Args ...) [with R = bool; Args = {const int&}]', declared with attribute 'nodiscard' [-Wunused-result]

   24 |   Function{&bar}(10);

      |   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~

<source>:12:19: note: declared here

   12 |   [[nodiscard]] R operator()(Args... args) {

      |                   ^~~~~~~~
```

EDIT:
Extend to member function (+const) + lambda ( with deduction guide )

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = std::void_t<>>
struct Function;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct Function<R (*)(Args...)> {
  using Fn = R (*)(Args...);

  Fn fn;

  explicit Function(Fn fn) : fn{fn} {}

  [[nodiscard]] R operator()(Args... args) {
    return fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};

template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
struct Function<R (T::*)(Args...)> {
  using MFn = R (T::*)(Args...);

  T* t;
  MFn mfn;

  Function(T* t, MFn mfn) : t{t}, mfn{mfn} {}

  [[nodiscard]] R operator()(Args... args) {
    return (t->*mfn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};

template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
struct Function<R (T::*)(Args...) const> {
  using MFn = R (T::*)(Args...) const;

  const T* t;
  MFn mfn;

  Function(const T* t, MFn mfn) : t{t}, mfn{mfn} {}

  [[nodiscard]] R operator()(Args... args) {
    return (t->*mfn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};

template <typename T>
struct Function<T, std::void_t<decltype(&T::operator())>> final
    : Function<decltype(&T::operator())> {
  explicit Function(const T& t)
      : Function<decltype(&T::operator())>(&t, &T::operator()) {}
};

template<typename T>
Function(T) -> Function<T>;

template<typename T, typename R, typename ...Args>
Function(T*, R(T::*)(Args...)) -> Function<R(T::*)(Args...)>;

template<typename T, typename R, typename ...Args>
Function(const T*, R(T::*)(Args...) const) -> Function<R(T::*)(Args...) const>;

void foo() {}

struct Foo
{
    void foo() const {}
};

int main() {
  Function{&foo}();
  Function{[]{}}();
  Foo foo{};
  Function{&foo, &Foo::foo}();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, while this is a good solution but the disadvantage is I can't use the standard `std::function` type anymore. I am more interested to know if I can make this type `nodiscard` qualified.

Comment: maybe something like this will do the trick, what functionality of std::function do you need? https://godbolt.org/z/xcs7sx

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap `std::function` or really a lambda directly to amend an attribute such as `[[nodiscard]]`.

Your comment about public inheritance being problematic is absolutely correct. However, this does not apply to private inheritance as you can control for these problems.
Edit: But if you absolutely don't like it, you can rewrite the code below to use a private member instead of private inheritance at the cost of making the code a bit more verbose but the benefit of supporting raw function pointers.

```
template <typename Function>
struct NoDiscard : private Function {
  NoDiscard() = default;
  NoDiscard(NoDiscard const&) = default;
  NoDiscard(NoDiscard&&) = default;
  NoDiscard& operator=(NoDiscard const&) = default;
  NoDiscard& operator=(NoDiscard&&) = default;

  NoDiscard(Function&& fn) : Function(std::move(fn)) {}
  NoDiscard(Function const& fn) : Function(fn) {}

  template <typename... Ts>
  [[nodiscard]] auto operator()(Ts&&... ts) {
    return Function::operator()(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  }
};

// convenience function to make the call look intuitive
template <typename Function>
auto add_nodiscard(Function&& f) {
  return NoDiscard<Function>(std::forward<Function>(f));
}
```

This will allow you to simply `add_nodiscard` to any functor or callable type. Example:

```
void test_good(auto fn) {
  (void)fn();
}
void test_bad(auto fn) {
  fn();
}


int main() {
  test_good(             (                         ([](){return true;})));
  test_bad (             (                         ([](){return true;})));
  test_good(add_nodiscard(                         ([](){return true;})));
  test_bad (add_nodiscard(                         ([](){return true;}))); // warns about discarded result

  test_good(             (std::function<bool(void)>([](){return true;})));
  test_bad (             (std::function<bool(void)>([](){return true;})));
  test_good(add_nodiscard(std::function<bool(void)>([](){return true;})));
  test_bad (add_nodiscard(std::function<bool(void)>([](){return true;}))); // warns about discarded result
}
```

**[live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1ffa49)**

This has the caveat that you *cannot* use this with a type that **must** receive a `std::function` object.

I believe such a goal to be impossible because you cannot change the type of a library function or add attributes directly to it. And any wrapper you add *before* the `std::function` call will have no effect regarding `[[nodiscard]]` simply because `std::function` will dutifully return the returned value from its callee.

*Disclaimer: I am saying that this absolutely impossible with the sole purpose of being proven wrong.*