# Why std::function accepts non-matching signatures

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, std-function

Consider this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

void foo(std::function<void(double)>) {}

template <typename T>
struct S {
    T function;
};

int main() {
    auto f = std::function<bool(double)>([](double) { return true; });
    foo(f);

    S<std::function<void(double)>> s;
    s.function = f;

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(f), std::function<void(double)>>);
}
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jn8xr1M1c)

Why is the call `foo(f)` possible with a different function type?

The assert says that they are not the same, yet it is not probem to provide a different function argument to `foo`.

What are the rules for conversions here?

And what can I do in case of the struct `S`, in which `s.function = f` can be assigned a not matching function?

Is there a way to avoid at compile time this assignment and only allow exact matching types?

Comment: `bool` is "convertible" to `void`.

Comment: @Jarod42 How can one avoid this conversion?

Comment: @Juergen You'll want something along the general lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63954142/nodiscard-in-stdfunction-return-type-definition

Comment: Here is [nice explanation how std::function (Type Erasure) works](https://youtu.be/tbUCHifyT24).

Comment: That's its job: it manages mismatches of argument and return types by applying legal conversions. If you don't want that sort of conversion, don't use `std::function`. `void func(void (*fptr)(double))` requires an exact match.